# Compiled java class file with ant and gradle are not matching

Tags: java, gradle, ant

I am in the process of migrating old ant project to gradle ones. I am using the same java version and same libraries in both Ant and Gradle. But the compiled .class files are not matching between ant and gradle. I was expecting both would match if we use same java version.

Am I doing anything wrong or is there an difference how ant and gradle creates the .class files?

Comment: What differences do you see? And what does it matter if the behavior stays the same? (Plus the fact that during runtime the code is interpreted/optimized by the JVM as well)

Comment: I first thought that there might be a timestamp in the class file, but well, that should not be the case.

Comment: @n247s I am not Nathan, but our ORG distributes updates to our software as **binary** patches to the class files in the field. It very much matters that the same source ends up in the exact same bytes everytime. So I understand that somebody might be expecting such behavior!

Comment: @GhostCat that will probably be the case if the same tool is used repeatedly to compile the same files. But Ant and gradle probably don't use the exact same flags, and if reproducibility is absolutely necessary, changing the tool is not the best way to achieve it. Using the verbose option in both tools should allow finding the which options are passed to the compiler.

Comment: @JBNizet Sure. That is why we freeze our build setup after each release; and changes go only into "head" ...

Comment: @GhostCat n247s JBNizet: when I de-compile both ant and gradle class files, I saw there been changes to variable names. In ant way the variable names are lengthier but in gradle the variable names are shorter. But still the .class file size is bigger than ant. I am not at my system right now. But if you want I can give some samples when I have access to my system.

Comment: As I dais, the Java compiler has several options which have an impact on the generated class files. If you just want to know why they differ, then the most probable answer is that they use different options. If you want to make them generate the same thing, then find what the options are, using the verbose option of ant and gradle.